# jenkins: how to graceful remove stuck executor when build and pod are all not exist

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How to graceful remove Jenkins stuck executor when:

1. Jenkins pipeline is running in kubernetes pod via kubernetes Plugin
2. build was removed due to Build History Rotation config ( automatically )
3. Kuberentes pod has been removed ( manually )

However, the item still show in Build Executor Status as below

[image]

got `java.lang.NullPointerException` via `WorkflowRun.finish`

[image]

---

even the build isn't exist anymore, but `Executor.isBusy()` and `Executor.isActive()` are all `true`.

`hudson.model.Executor` details:

[image]

And `SubTask.isContinued()` also shows `true` as well.

`SubTask` ( `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.ExecutorStepExecution.PlaceholderTask` ) details:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

algith, it can be simply "force removed" by kill the executor via:

```
jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance
                     .computers.collect { c -> c.executors }
                     .collectMany { it.findAll{ it.isBusy() } }
                     .each { it.interrupt() }
```

execute in your https://<jenkins.domain.com>/script